# What is the difference between 折磨 and 煎熬?

Tags: difference

the meaning are almost the same，but
她折磨我✔
她煎熬我✘
我的内心很折磨✘
我的内心很煎熬✔

我被受中文折磨✅ 煎熬✅
中文让我感到十分煎熬✅ 十分折磨❓ is a bit strange

为什么会这样？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 折 - break

> 磨 - grind

> 折磨 - torture; torment; suffering

~

> 煎 - fry in oil or cook in water

> 熬 - slow cook with water

> 煎熬 - torture; torment; suffering

Both 折磨 and 煎熬 means 'torture'

折磨 emphasize the application of torture (apply force to cause pain). That's why we use 折磨 instead of 煎熬 for the verb 'to torture' e.g. 折磨他一晚 (torture him a whole night) not 煎熬他一晚

煎熬 emphasize the effect of torture (feel the pain of being boiled). 內心煎熬 (suffer inside) actually mean 內心受煎熬 (feel tortured inside)

Similarly, 內心折磨 (suffer inside) actually mean 內心受折磨 (feel tortured inside)

> 她折磨我✔ 她煎熬我✘ 我的内心很折磨✘ 我的内心很煎熬✔

- 她折磨我✔ - the verb 折磨 (to torture) is correctly placed between the subject and object
- 她煎熬我✘ - 煎熬 is not used as a verb for to 'torture'
- 我的内心很折磨✘  - 我的内心很受折磨✔ - 折磨 is an action while 受折磨 can be a feeling
- 我的内心很煎熬✔ - In this context, 煎熬 strongly imply 受煎熬 (a feeling)

> 我被受中文折磨✅

> 我被受中文煎熬✅

我備受中文煎熬 is correct because it is [備受(v)]~[煎熬(n)]

中文折磨我✔ (*grammatically correct, but the subject 中文 and the verb don't quite match. How does 中文 折磨 someone?*)

中文煎熬我✘

- '被受' should be '[備受](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/13525)' (receive)

Comment: Are these sentences right?
Correct these sentences if they are wrong please

1.他正在监狱里受煎熬。
2. 他久病不愈, 受尽煎熬。
3.在外国统治下饱受煎熬的国家。
4.我备受良心的煎熬, 犹豫着到底该不该把这封信寄出去。

Comment: @jinglingmen All the sentences are valid. [受(v) + 煎熬(n)] -->  [受煎熬 (v)]

Comment: ♦   thank you so much

Comment: 简直就是一种折磨=简直就是一种煎熬？

Comment: @jinglingmen 折磨 express more about the physical aspect of torture; 煎熬 express more about the mental aspect of torture. Make a  child study for ten hours straight is physical and mental torture, therefore, you can call it 折磨 or 煎熬; Make a Navy SEALs member swim for ten miles in cold water in full gear is more a 折磨 than 煎熬.  Also, 简直就是一种折磨 refers to torture applied more; 简直就是一种煎熬  refers to  torture perceived more